# Semi colon usage - for situation and conclusion

Tags: grammar, semicolons

I think I correctly wrote this sentence, but I wanted to double check.

> I was thinking about this; I think I was confused.

I barely use semicolons, and wanted to make sure this was right.

Comment: It is correct. Semicolons can seem a bit formal depending on context though. It's increasingly popular to use an em dash instead, or even ellipses in informal cases.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Lexico puncuation guide](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/punctuation).

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the answer.